# Mixes not translating

Tags: mixing, mastering, music-production-station

I have tried many things but for some reason mixes don't sound thick.I have this question my mixes are not translating properly is there any video or article that could help me??
thank you
regards

Comment: If your mixes aren't portable the first suspect is your mix environment. Logically, if they sound good in only one place, that place is 'wrong'. See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45587/mixing-and-mastering-at-home?rq=1 and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/how-to-judge-a-mix-on-e-g-muddiness-and-balance?rq=1

Comment: Welcome! Maybe it's because I'm not an audio engineer, but I don't know what you mean by "translating." Could you edit to explain more? If this isn't a technical issue, but just one of "feel," you might have to get a lot more specific to find a solution. Also, Stack Exchange tries to create substantive answers *here*; they might link to an article or a video, but questions that are only looking for outside resources aren't one of the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Tetsujin (I've also had the "the mixing environment is 'too right'" phenomenon. "Holy crap, this bass sounds awesome!" ... in the studio, with a subwoofer like a filing cabinet. Bounce it down to CD, stick it in a boombox, and it's inaudible.

Comment: youtube youtube youtube.  You can watch videos about mixing until the cows come home.  Just search.

Comment: Also, you mention 2 separate issues.  1) Mixes not translating is likely indicative of poor room acoustics and/or crappy monitors in your mixing room.  2) Mixes not sounding thick enough might be because you're scooping out too much of the midrange.  Overly hyped mixes sound thin.